# React Swiper with thumbs recalculate slides count incorrectly (its adding slides instead of replacing)

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

i faced with a problem, i have a react project with react-router-dom. I have a product item page (dynamic route), which, for example, have T-shirt data with different colors, clicking by them changes dynamic route to passed item path. On this page i have a swiper with thumbs, illustrating some product images, but when i change the route, all my data is updating, but slider remains the same (even thumbs slider updates correclty).
To be precise, i have a catalogue of products, then open some of these items it makes request to get data and i pass that data to all my components and slider too. I thought then you pass new data, swiper will rerender content based on it, but it concat them so it works incorrectly. Sorry for my english, it's not my primary language.

Here's the code of sliders and it's styles:

```
import { FC, useState } from 'react'
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css'
import 'swiper/css/free-mode'
import 'swiper/css/navigation'
import 'swiper/css/thumbs'

// import required modules
import SwiperCore, { FreeMode, Navigation, Pagination, Thumbs } from 'swiper'
import { IConsumableData } from '../../../../../../types/api'
import { BASE_MEDIA } from '../../../../../../api/_variables'
import NavArrow, { NavArrowStatus } from '../../../../../UI/IconsSvg/NavArrow/NavArrow'
import ExpandIcon from '../../../../../UI/IconsSvg/ExpandIcon/ExpandIcon'

import 'react-medium-image-zoom/dist/styles.css'
import styles from './ConsumableCardPreview.module.scss'
import './ConsumableCardPreviewSwiper.scss'
interface ConsumableCardPreviewProps {
  consumable: IConsumableData
}

const ConsumableCardPreview: FC<ConsumableCardPreviewProps> = ({ consumable }) => {
  const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState<SwiperCore>()
  const [mainSwiper, setMainSwiper] = useState<SwiperCore>()
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0)
  const [isZoomed, setIsZoomed] = useState(false)

  const handlePrev = () => {
    if (mainSwiper) {
      mainSwiper.slidePrev()
    }
  }
  console.log(consumable);
  const handleNext = () => {
    if (mainSwiper) {
      mainSwiper.slideNext()
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.previewContainer}>
      <div className={styles.consumableSwipersWrapper}>
        <Swiper
          onSwiper={setMainSwiper}
          spaceBetween={10}
          onInit={(swiper) => {
            swiper.init()
          }}
          navigation
          pagination={{
            type: 'bullets',
            clickable: false,
            renderBullet: function () {
              return '<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span>'
            }
          }}
          thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper && !thumbsSwiper.destroyed ? thumbsSwiper : null }}
          modules={[FreeMode, Thumbs, Navigation, Pagination]}
          className={styles.mainConsumableSwiper}
          onSlideChange={(swiper) => {
            setCurrentSlide(swiper.realIndex)
          }}
        >
          {consumable.images.map((image) => (
            <SwiperSlide className={styles.mainSwiperSlide} key={image.product_id}>
              <img src={`${BASE_MEDIA}${image.image}`} className={styles.mainSwiperImage} />
              <ExpandIcon className={styles.zoomIcon} onClick={() => setIsZoomed(true)} />
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </Swiper>

        <div className={styles.thumbsWrapper}>
          <div className={styles.thumbsPrev}>
            <NavArrow
              status={currentSlide === 0 ? NavArrowStatus.DISABLED : NavArrowStatus.ACTIVE}
              onClick={() => handlePrev()}
            />
          </div>
          <Swiper
            modules={[FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs]}
            onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
            spaceBetween={10}
            slidesPerView={3}
            direction={'vertical'}
            navigation={false}
            watchSlidesProgress={true}
            className={styles.thumbsConsumableSwiper}
            breakpoints={{
              800: {
                slidesPerView: 4
              },
              1000: {
                slidesPerView: 3
              }
            }}
          >
            {consumable.images.map((image) => (
              <SwiperSlide className={styles.thumbsSlide} key={image.image}>
                <img src={`${BASE_MEDIA}${image.image}`} />
              </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
          </Swiper>
          <div className={styles.thumbsNext}>
            <NavArrow
              status={
                currentSlide === consumable.images.length - 1
                  ? NavArrowStatus.DISABLED
                  : NavArrowStatus.ACTIVE
              }
              onClick={() => handleNext()}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ConsumableCardPreview
```

```
@use '../../ConsumableCardContent.module.scss' as column;
@use '/src/styles/variables' as var;

$gap: 3.75rem;

.previewContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.consumableSwipersWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: calc(column.$autoColumnWidth - $gap) 1fr;
  gap: $gap;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;

  @media (max-width: var.$tablet-size) {
    padding-inline: 1.875rem;
    position: relative;
    gap: 2rem;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 6.25rem) 1fr;
  }

  @media (max-width: var.$mobile-size) {
    padding-inline: 0;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    min-height: 0;
  }
}

.mainConsumableSwiper {
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;

  @media (max-width: var.$mobile-size) {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
  }
}

.mainSwiperSlide {
  cursor: grab;
  position: relative;
}

.mainSwiperImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  pointer-events: none;

  @media (max-width: var.$mobile-size) {
    object-fit: contain;
  }
}

.zoomIcon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 2%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.thumbsWrapper {
  order: -1;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;

  @media (max-width: var.$mobile-size) {
    display: none;
  }
}

.thumbsConsumableSwiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-block: auto;
}

.thumbsSlide {
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
  @media (max-width: var.$tablet-size) {
    max-width: 6.25rem;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  }
}

.thumbsPrev,
.thumbsNext {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;

  & > img {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}

.thumbsNext {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

I thought it will rerender slides correctly depending on data passed, but everything works perfect, even thumbs slider, but main slider not working as expected.
I've tried to add useEffect and destroy and init swiper again, i've tried to add event like onDestroy, onInit, onSlidesLengthChange, i've tried swiper.update() etc etc etc. Everything i found on the web i've tried and it did not bring any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, for someone who faced with the same problem - i solved it by force updating swiper, passing key prop to it with updated state, which i update with new coming data
`const [key, setKey] = useState<number>(1)  useEffect(() => {setKey(prev => ++prev)}, [yourNewComingData])  <Swiper key={key}`